# Determine the input shape for an LSTM network in tensorflow.js

Tags: node.js, lstm, tensorflow.js

I am trying to build and train an LSTM network in tensorflow.js,

my Dataset is like

```
dataSet = [
 {
    phrase: "i am returning this product because it is too yellow for me",
    output: "color"
},
{
    phrase: "i am shipping back product because it is broken when i received it",
    output: "broken"
},
{
    phrase: "not satisfied because handle broke after using for three days",
    output: "quality issue"
}

];
```

I can make each word into an 300 dimensional vector(to be simple array of length 300) using google's wordtovec pre-trained model,

next part where I am stuck is, could not determine the input and output shapes for an LSTM network. If i can get a vector output from the model, i guess i can make string out of that vector.

So can anyone guide me in giving input to LSTM network if i have variable length input and output.

Comment: You need to either pad or cut each 'phrase' vector to a dynamically produced (fixed) size

Answer (score 0):

The input and output shape of the network can be determined in many ways. But the classical way of solving the problem is to use what is called the [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model). The idea is the following: you build the vocabulary or corpus of your systems which represents all the words one my encounter in your inputs.

**1. The input data dimension is the same as the corpus.**

With this model, the input data are very big and contains a lot of 0s. This is called [sparse data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). It requires a lot of time and computation given the size of the architecture that is needed to train all the parameters. To counteract this limitation, one might use an embedding layer inside the network in order to decrease the number of dimensions.

**2. The input data contains only the elements that occur**

Each input data is constructed using the index of the words given the corpus. The only issue is how to tell how many words one will have in advance. Well, even if the inputs size are random, the inputs shape should take into account the maximum size the network could have as input. And if the input size if less than what it should be, you can increase its size by adding 0s.

The same reasoning holds for the outputs